# How to set a default volume? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, volume-control

I have a problem with the default volume on my computer, everytime it starts it set the volume to 100%, I tried to change it, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/476625/374167), Set the volume to your desired level and then:

`sudo alsactl store`

This does what you want, system-wide.