# How to control volume from file system in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, filesystem, output

I have found out that brightness can be controlled from a file /dev/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness. I am looking for a similar file from where I can change system volume ( sound ).
I am not looking for a terminal command like given in the post at [Terminal command to set audio volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97936/terminal-command-to-set-audio-volume)
but looking for the file that is changes by it (where it records the sounds info)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, my laptop is hp-pavillion.

Comment: @EliahKagan Based on the edited question, this may help: [Set default pulseaudio volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476619/set-default-pulseaudio-volume)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. With the way your question is currently worded the linked duplicate appears to fit perfectly. Why do you assume that the volume can be controlled with or stored in a file like the backlight brightness? Are you looking for a way to restore it after reboot?