# How to save Settings changes to become defaults?

Tags: sound, settings, default

OK, regrettably, I have another noob question.

While 22.04.4 makes changing mic and speaker selections quite easy, for some reason the changes I make don't "stick" and every time I restart the computer the settings revert to default values (not what I want).

It seems, from researching earlier comments, that changing default settings 'permanently' is a relatively common problem. I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious and easy but I can't seem to find it. Argh.

{:-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set default pulseaudio volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476619/set-default-pulseaudio-volume)

Comment: @Daniel T, that is helpful info but having to adjust volume levels is something I long ago got used to doing given the wild variations in recording levels between sources.

What I'm trying to find is a way to set new defaults in Settings for varying DEVICES (particularly mics and speakers). Mint used to retain Settings changes 'automatically' and I didn't realize how much I'd miss that functionality when I switched to Ubuntu. (Fussy, lazy rascal that I am ...)

But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Its answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/892713/1004020 is per-sink (analogously per-source). I use Kubuntu and never needed this workaround

Comment: I'll check it out when I return. Thanks!